# How to insert date and Query date in SQLite table

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am not familiar with SQLite on handling date.

The problem:

1. Can I insert date this way or insert any date using DateTime to create.

   Order_Date = DateTime.Today

How to :

a) How to use a select or query a recordset base or Order_Date ?

b) How to select or query a recordset base on Date Range ? from this date to this date.

Thanks

```
      Class Order
      {
     [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int SId { get; set; }
        public int CustId { get; set; }     
        public string No { get; set; }        
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public DateTime Order_Date { get; set; }

      }



   using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
     {
        var newOrder = new Order()
        {
           CustId = g_intCustId,
           Customer = txtBlkCustomer.Text.Trim(),
           Order_Date = DateTime.Today   

        };

   db.Insert(newOrder);


----- Update : 


1) I wanted to know what is the proper way to insert date into a field of dateTime DataType in table as Above? using Date from DateTime.Today, DateTime.Now 

2) what fields need to add in SQLite table when enter Date with 

a) normal Date format ( dd/mm/yyyy)

b) format like :  Date with  HHMMSS

3) How to query or select Date for (2a) and (2b)?


Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can I insert date this way or insert any date using DateTime to create.
`Order_Date = DateTime.Today`**

Yes, `DateTime.Today` while insertion will work. SQLite internally stores `DateTime` objects as string.

**How to use a select or query a recordset base or Order_Date ?**

```csharp
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\aaa.sqlite"))
{
    // You can use any one
    var list2 = db.Query<Order>("SELECT * FROM Order WHERE Order_Date = datetime('2013-10-01')", "");

    var list3 = db.Query<Order>("SELECT * FROM Order WHERE Order_Date = ?", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5));
}
```

**How to select or query a recordset base on Date Range ? from this date to this date.**

```csharp
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\aaa.sqlite"))
{
    // You can use any one
    var list = db.Query<Order>("SELECT * FROM Order WHERE Order_Date BETWEEN datetime('2013-10-01') AND datetime('2013-10-07')", "");

    var list1 = db.Query<Order>("SELECT * FROM Order WHERE Order_Date BETWEEN ? AND ?", DateTime.Today.AddDays(-9), DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3));
}
```

[SQLite Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Isn't `datetime('2013-10-07')` pointless? This will return `'2013-10-07 00:00:00'`. What about a order at `2013-10-07 12:00:00`? It will be out of query!

Comment: I have used `datetime('2013-10-07')` because the OP is passing order date as `DateTime.Today` not `DateTime.Now`

Comment: So, better to use `date()`! And use literal `'2013-10-07'`, as function call is not doing anything!

Comment: Is there a different between date() and datetime() for SQLite? The literal must follow by year,Day,Month ( British date) or Usa date :year,Month,Day.  I am not sure.

Comment: `date()` will parse only date, it won't accept time. Fot literal format please see [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Say DateTime is :2013-10-07 01:10:03, then I insert it in to SQLite tblOrder as follow :
Order_Date = DateTime.Today .  Will this Order_Date contains the same as  '2013-10-07 01:10:03'?  If not, how to handle the Time part> 01:10:03 ?

Comment: Yes it will be stored as `2013-10-07 01:10:03`. SQLite stores date-time as string.

Answer (score 0):

Go thorough bellow link

[Windows Phone 7 Native Database Programming via Sqlite Client for Windows Phone](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx)

[SQLite-WinRT: Database programming on Windows Phone and Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/06/06/sqlite-winrt-database-programming-on-windows-phone-and-windows-8.aspx)

[How to use SQLite in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone)

Hope it will help you

Comment: Can I use SQLite-Net and SQLite-WinRT Together in WinRT app for the same SQLite Database created?

Comment: @MilkBottle:yes but my suggestion is you  use Windows Phone 7 Native Database Programming via Sqlite Client for Windows Phone.bcos its become very easy for you